# Timer maximum and minimum resolution

Tags: timer

I am having a development board and it has system clock of 32 bit timer 48Mhz .if i want to find the maximum resolution with pre-scale value how to find it.
This pre-scale has 16 bits and how could i use it to make timer delay of 1 s or more

I know that 1/48Mhz = 0.02083us and 32 bit ==>2^32=4294967279

but how i make use of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in MCU, the peripherals, like timers, are not the Oscillator input.

You have PLLs that actually increases the frequency, and then divisor that reduces the frequency clock for some peripherals.

It means, Timer1 might have a different clock speed than Timer 2 for example. This is very dependent on the chip and the datasheet needs to be checked.

This is not to be confused with the prescaler, which is another addition to further reduce the clock speed on your timer.

If your timer really has a clock speed of 48Mhz, then it's quite simple, minimum resolution, 1 tick is 1/48Mhz, maximum is 1/48Mhz * 2^32 = 89 seconds.

If you use prescaler, then just multiply by the prescaler, so prescaler of 2 = 178.9s.

Comment: I am having prescale register of 16 , is that mean i can prescale up to 2^16 times(65536)

Comment: You are looking at it a bit backward but yes. 48Mhz / 16 / 2^32 if you have a 32bit timer so 23 minutes. If you need longer, you can always add a counter in the timer interrupt.

Comment: If i give prescale value for 16 bit as 0xffff , what will be the timer resolution for 32 bit (48Mhz) . can you please explain it in calculation.

Comment: 48Mhz/16.......